# How to @return a class attribute and it be included in the documentation

Tags: c++, doxygen, documentation-generation

How can I set the return of a class method (flagged const) to be a class attribute, so doxygen highlightes it in the documentation?

Check the illustration:

```
class A
{
int attribute;

 public:
int getAttribute()const;  //<<- I need this return to show that it is atrribute
}
```

I have tried to use the following: neither `@return attribute` nor `@return $attribute` did work and I don't have any other idea

Comment: \return just contains the description of the value to be returned not there is no "parameter name". Maybe you can do something wit \ref or \copydoc or \copybrief.